# Changing line spacing only within a \cfrac expression

Tags: line-spacing

There are a few questions asking how to change line spacing in table or equation environments, for example.  The usual solution is to do something like

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately the \cfrac command is not an environment, so this doesn't work.  Is there a similar solution to the above using patchcmd?  My thesis style file uses a baselineskip of 1.6 if that matters, and this makes cfractions way too vertically spaced.

I'm using the article class with 11pt font and the style file has the line

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.7}
```

Also the style file changes back to single spacing in figures and footnotes using such code as

```
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup 
    \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
    \boxmaxdepth\z@
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}
```

Hopefully there's a way to do something like this for cfractions.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and how you're modifying `\baselineskip` (or maybe `\baselinestretch`?) at present.

Comment: It's the article class and the command in the style file is 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.7}.  I just updated my question to this effect and gave additional style file information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the attached output, but I reduced the space 'manually'. Maybe you can make a macro of it.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}%
\setstretch{2.6}
```

This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.\

```
\textbf{This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.}\\

{$\setstretch{1.2}
\cfrac[r]{a}{b}$}\\
abeeeee deeeee fkkkkkkkk abeeeee deeeee fkkkkkkkk abeeeee deeeee fkkkkkkkk abeeeee deeeee fkkkkkkkk abeeeee deeeee fkkkkkkkk%
\end{document}%
```

[image: setstretch]